# Entries in a dictionary all have the same value though they are created individually

Tags: excel, vba

I have a excel table for a `1:n-Relationship`

```
ID  value
----------
1   A
1   B
1   C
2   A
2   B
3   F
4   X
4   Z
```

And a object (`CValueMap`) which should store the values for a given ID:

```
Option Explicit

Public id As Integer
Public values As Collection
```

I read the excel table by iterating the rows, creating the `CValueMap` (if it doesn't exist in my dictionary yet) and filling the values.

```
Dim idCell As Range
Dim allValues As New Scripting.Dictionary
allValues.RemoveAll

For Each idCell In Range("id_value_table[ID]")
    If Not allValues.Exists(idCell.value) Then
        Dim newValueMap As New CValueMap
        newValueMap.id = idCell.value
        Set newValueMap.values = New Collection
        allValues.Add idCell.value, newValueMap
    End If

    Dim valueMap As CValueMap
    Set valueMap = allValues.Item(idCell.value)
    valueMap.values.Add idCell.Offset(0, 1).value
Next idCell
```

I would now assume that I have 4 `CValueMap`s where the first one has `ABC`, the second `AB`, the third `F` and the last `XZ` as values. This, however is not the case as this code shows:

```
'iterate allValues
Dim singleKey as Variant
For Each singleKey In allValues.Keys
    Debug.Print singleKey & " has these values:"
    Debug.Print "ID: " & allValues.Item(singleKey).id
    Dim value As Variant
    For Each value In allValues.Item(singleKey).values
        Debug.Print "  " & value
    Next value
Next singleKey
```

.

```
---------------OUTPUT:-------------------
1 has these values:
ID: 4
  X
  Z
2 has these values:
ID: 4
  X
  Z
3 has these values:
ID: 4
  X
  Z
4 has these values:
ID: 4
  X
  Z
```

I'm not really sure where I went wrong. From the behaviour I assumed the **same** ValueMap might have been written to **each** entry in the `allValues` dictionary, but since I did create 4 distinct ones and load them correctly before adding the `value`s I fail to see where this could have happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Object lesson for you - **NEVER** use `Dim... As New...` as you can't control when or if you get a new object.

Simple changes to your code required:

```
Dim idCell                As Range
Dim allValues             As Scripting.Dictionary
Dim newValueMap           As CValueMap

Set allValues = New Scripting.Dictionary
allValues.RemoveAll

For Each idCell In Range("id_value_table[ID]")
    If Not allValues.Exists(idCell.value) Then
        Set newValueMap = New CValueMap
        newValueMap.id = idCell.value
        Set newValueMap.values = New Collection
        allValues.Add idCell.value, newValueMap
    End If

    Dim valueMap          As CValueMap
    Set valueMap = allValues.Item(idCell.value)
    valueMap.values.Add idCell.Offset(0, 1).value
Next idCell
```

Comment: So `Dim... as New...` isn't actually just a short way to write `Dim ...` and `Set ... = New ...`? There are probably quite a few guides on the internet which need to be updated then. Thanks this solved my problem!

Comment: It is, pretty much, but it's equivalent to having both those two lines at the top of your procedure and outside your loop, so you only get the object variable created once. IMO, it's lazy and dangerous. You could have kept that syntax and added `Set newValueMap = Nothing` after adding the object to the dictionary but I still think's it bad programming.

Answer (score 0):

Just before your End If, add this line:

```
Set newValueMap = Nothing
```